# If ID has both values A and B it should return AB

Tags: sql, string, window-functions

INPUT:

```
ID  VALUES
1    A
1    B
2    A
3    B
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID   VALUES
1    AB
1    AB
2    A
3    B
```

If ID has both values A and B it should return AB.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And why do you want the result set to have duplicate rows?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing string aggregation as a window function. In standard ANSI SQL, the syntax would be:

```
select id, listagg(values) within group(order by values) over(partition by id) values
from mytable
```

Not all databases support this syntax though. In MySQL, you would use `group_concat()`, in Postgres, that's `string_agg()`, and so on - but the logic remains the same.